# Do we have tags for author services?

Tags: discussion, tags

Looking at this question: [What is the name of the service or job title for typing handwritten manuscripts?](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/32361/what-is-the-name-of-the-service-or-job-title-for-typing-handwritten-manuscripts)

The only tag on there is [typing](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/typing).  I looked but could not come up with another one that was appropriate.  While that's okay—sometimes a post only needs one tag, even a very low usage one—it made me realize that there was not a tag for auxiliary services that an author uses.

Many legitimate questions on Writing.SE deal with a variety of author services:

- Typing
- Transcription
- Translation (there is a [translation](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/translation) tag for the act of translating, but not for the process of finding/using a translator)
- Submission services
- Formatting a work for publication, including getting the ISBN number, putting the work on library ordering systems, all those things that publishers do and that author service companies do for self-publishers.
- Proofreading (there is a [tag:proofreading) tag) but it says "This tag should be used for questions that are about proofreading your work or the work of someone else."  That may or may not cover finding and using a paid proofreader.
- Editing (there is an [tag:editing) tag) but it says "Questions with this tag should focus on specific editing techniques or ways to improve editing skills." That doesn't cover finding and using a paid editor.

Is there something I'm missing?

Should we create [author-services](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/author-services) or something similar?  (Meaning, is it okay if *I* create it?)  We want to discourage questions asking for referrals (though it's okay to a degree, like when people ask for printers who do specific work) but I think we can handle any spammy questions or answers that come along.

Or do we want to expand some of the wiki on existing tags to allow for hiring of services and perhaps put the leftover into [tools](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tools)?

Answer (score 1):

Such a tag seems sensible.

Maybe just shorten to "Services" in general?

Asking for *specific service providers* sounds problematic and off-topic, but questions leaning towards expectations or usefulness of a *type* of service seems like useful content.

- "How do I do X thing if I am hiring this work out to Y kind of service?"
- "If I pay someone to do A, would it be appropriate to expect B formatting in return?"
- "I need to do this thing, what kind of company should I be looking for?"
- "How much of X should I have done before considering sending out for Y service?"

They might not get a huge amount of use, but I could see the utility in such questions and such a tag to organize them.

Comment: I could also see things like "is this type of service worthwhile?"  so I'm a YES for the tag.